# How to refresh div content in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$('#example').load(window.location.pathname+'#example');
```

after ajax call in success, but it is loading whole page in a div.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Appending #example to the end of a URL does not cause only that *part* of the URL to load.   The entire thing loads... it only drops you to the specific part of the page.   Probably not the best method for what you want here...

Comment: Please suggest me the other way.

Comment: @Charlie74: Loading a page fragment by providing a selector is a built-in functionality of `load`.  However, it needs to be provided as a selector seperated by a space from the URL.  Otherwise, it is interpreted as a URL with an anchor tag.

Comment: @JeffB good to know...  thanks Jeff.    Wouldn't have guessed that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a space:

```
$('#example').load(window.location.pathname+' #example');
```

According to the documentation example, there should be a space before the selector:

http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Is the pagination not in the same selector? Is it generated by JS?  If either of these is the case, you will have issues. It is hard to say without seeing more code.

Comment: Then you will have to rerun that JS after load, if possible, or come up with another way to get the pagination.

Comment: Thanks Jeff I will look in it

Answer (score -1):

The code to load the div is fine.

You need to look into the content returned by url. It seem `window.location.pathname+'#example'` returns the whole page.

Comment: Yes, it does return the whole page, but jQuery provides the functionality to automatically grab out the selector you want by doing `.load("path/to/url #myselector")`.  The OP is simply missing a space.  http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments